# A branch of $\sqrt{z^2-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the branch of $\sqrt{z^2-1}$ with the condition that $\sqrt{z^2-1} \sim z $ as $ \ z \to \infty$, the branch cut is $[-1,1]$

With the above branch, Now consider the function $$f(z)=\frac{1+i\sqrt{z^2-1} \sin(\frac{\alpha}{2})}{1+i z \tan(\frac{\alpha}{2})} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 0 < \alpha < \pi$$
With the chosen branch  why $f(-i \cot(\frac{\alpha}{2})) =1$ and why $f(i \cot(\frac{\alpha}{2})) = \cos^2(\frac{\alpha}{2})$ ?

I think I do not correctly understand the branch, I really appreciate a detailed explanation. Thanks !

Comment: What is $\alpha$?

Comment: The word 'the' in "Consider the branch..." assumes that there is such a branch and it is unique. Must you show it?

Comment: @GFauxPas sorry, I just edited the question, $\alpha$ is any angle between $0$ and $\pi$.

Comment: @ajotatxe That is correct, showing the existence and uniqueness at least helps me better understand the branch.

Comment: Are you taking the interval $[-1,1]$ as the branch cut?

Comment: @DanielFischer I thought taking a particular branch cut is equivalent to choosing a branch of $\sqrt{z^2-1}$ ( Am I right ?), which is maybe my main question, because as I said, I think I do not understand the branch correctly...

Comment: Not quite. Choosing the branch cut determines the domain of the function. Then there are always two branches, differing by a factor of $-1$ [and if you're mad enough to take a branch cut such that its complement has $k > 1$ connected components, you have $2^k$ branches]. The "canonical" choices for the branch cut for $\sqrt{z^2-1}$ are $[-1,1]$ and $(-\infty,-1] \cup [1,+\infty)$. On the domain you get from the latter choice, there is no branch satisfying $\sqrt{z^2-1} \sim z$ for $\lvert z\rvert$ large, however, so that is out. But you could still choose half the unit circle for the cut,

Comment: or some other curve from $-1$ to $1$. But these choices are artificial, for some of these choices the points of interest lie on the branch cut, and for some choices, the assertion is false. So on the whole, $[-1,1]$ is the overwhelmingly probable branch cut, but it's not explicitly stated so far.

Comment: Thanks ! Okay, let me see why$(-\infty, -1] \cup [1,\infty)$ does not work? is it because the branch "goes through" $\infty$ and hence $\sqrt{z^2-1} \not\sim z$ for $|z|$ large ?!
I will state in the problem that $[-1,1]$ is the branch cut.

Comment: If you take $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{ t\in \mathbb{R} : \lvert t\rvert \geqslant 1\}$ as the domain, then if you have $\sqrt{z^2-1} \sim z$ for large $\lvert z\rvert$ in the upper half-plane, you have $\sqrt{z^2-1}\sim -z$ for large $\lvert z\rvert$ in the lower half-plane. Roughly speaking, "the root flips the sign when passing through the cut".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the branch cut $[-1,1]$, the domain $U = \mathbb{C}\setminus \{ z : \lvert z\rvert \leqslant 1\}$, the exterior of the unit disk, is contained in the domain of the branch of $h(z) = \sqrt{z^2-1}$ we choose. On the open unit disk, we have two branches of $\sqrt{1-w}$, let $g(w)$ denote the branch with $g(0) = 1$. Then we can write

$$h(z) = z\cdot g\biggl(\frac{1}{z^2}\biggr) = z\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{z^2}}$$

on $U$. For purely imaginary $z \in U$, we have $\frac{1}{z^2}$ real and negative, so it follows that $1-\frac{1}{z^2} > 0$, and thus $g\bigl(\frac{1}{z^2}\bigr) > 0$.

Hence for $z = it,\, t\in \mathbb{R}, \lvert t\rvert > 1$, we have

$$f(it) = \frac{1 + ih(it)\sin\bigl(\frac{\alpha}{2}\bigr)}{1 + i(it)\tan \bigl(\frac{\alpha}{2}\bigr)} = \frac{1 -tg\bigl(-\frac{1}{t^2}\bigr)\sin\bigl(\frac{\alpha}{2}\bigr)}{1 - t\tan\bigl(\frac{\alpha}{2}\bigr)} = \frac{1 - \sigma(t)\sqrt{t^2+1}\sin\bigl(\frac{\alpha}{2}\bigr)}{1 - t\tan\bigl(\frac{\alpha}{2}\bigr)},$$

where $\sigma(t)$ is the sign of $t$.

By the identity theorem, this holds for all $t\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$. For $0 < \alpha < \pi$, we have $\operatorname{trig} \bigl(\frac{\alpha}{2}\bigr) > 0$, where $\operatorname{trig}$ stands for any of the trigonometric functions $\sin,\cos,\tan, \cot$. So inserting $t = -\cot\bigl(\frac{\alpha}{2}\bigr)$, after using

$$\sqrt{\cot^2\bigl(\tfrac{\alpha}{2}\bigr) + 1} = \sqrt{\frac{\cos^2\bigl(\frac{\alpha}{2}\bigr) + \sin^2\bigl(\frac{\alpha}{2}\bigr)}{\sin^2\bigl(\frac{\alpha}{2}\bigr)}} = \frac{1}{\sin\bigl(\frac{\alpha}{2}\bigr)},\tag{$\ast$}$$

we obtain

$$f\bigl(-i\cot\bigl(\frac{\alpha}{2}\bigr)\bigr) = \frac{1 - (-1)\frac{\sin (\alpha/2)}{\sin(\alpha/2)}}{1 - (-1)\cot\bigl(\frac{\alpha}{2}\bigr)\tan\bigl(\frac{\alpha}{2}\bigr)} = \frac{1+1}{1+1} = 1.$$

For $t = +\cot \bigl(\frac{\alpha}{2}\bigr)$, if we just plug that into the formula for $f$, we get the indeterminate form $\frac{1-1}{1-1}$, so we must determine the value in some other manner. In some places of the world l'Hôpital's rule is popular, in other places Taylor expansions are more often used. Here is one of the rare places where I prefer l'Hôpital's rule, which leads us to

$$\frac{-\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}\sin\bigl(\frac{\alpha}{2}\bigr)}{-\tan\bigl(\frac{\alpha}{2}\bigr)}$$

into which $t = \cot \bigl(\frac{\alpha}{2}\bigr)$ shall be plugged. That yields - with $(\ast)$ -

$$\frac{\cot\bigl(\frac{\alpha}{2}\bigr)\sin^2\bigl(\frac{\alpha}{2}\bigr)}{\tan\bigl(\frac{\alpha}{2}\bigr)} = \cot^2\biggl(\frac{\alpha}{2}\biggr)\sin^2\biggl(\frac{\alpha}{2}\biggr) = \cos^2 \biggl(\frac{\alpha}{2}\biggr).$$